Pusher Connection not authorized within timeout
I am using vue js 2 with Laravel.
this.$echo.connector.connect();
const channel = this.$echo.channel(
        `stream-siganls.${stream.id}`
);
channel.listen("StreamSignalEvent", async (event) => {
        if (!!event.is_live) {
            this.otherUser.stream.is_live = event.is_live;
        }
});

In network -> ws, first its establishes the connection. {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{"socket_id":"191820.120504","activity_timeout":120}"}
then subscribe to the channel,
{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"","channel":"stream-signals.1000101"}}
but then it returs this,
{"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":4009,"message":"Connection not authorized within timeout"}}   after 30 seconds of connection established.
I have used pusher as broadcaster and vue-echo-laravel package.
This issue only happens if there is no message sent over channel till 30 seconds of its established.
